Unable to create JSON matrix object for workflow
When I set $i -lt 3 it loops twice and creates two entries. The GitHub PowerShell workflow is able to generate matrix with two jobs which is good.

But when I set $i -lt 2 I expect it to generate matrix with single job but it does not.

name: Generate Matrix

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  generate-matrix:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      DISMATRIX: ${{ steps.matrix.outputs.DISMATRIX }}
    steps:
      - name: Set up Git repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Generate Matrix
        id: matrix
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          $dismatrix = @()
          $counter = 1
          
          # Single Loop
          for ($i = 1; $i -lt 2; $i++) {
            $statcustomenvName = "StatCustomEnvName$counter"
            $customenvName = "CustomEnvName$counter"

            # Increment the counter
            $counter++

            # Add unique values to the $dismatrix array
            $dismatrix += @{
              "DISPLAYLIST" = $statcustomenvName
              "CUSTOMENVNAME" = $customenvName
            }
          }

          
          # Output the matrix as JSON
          echo "DISMATRIX=$($dismatrix | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100)" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"

      
  Trigger_Service:
    name: "${{ matrix.DISPLAYLIST }}"
    needs: [generate-matrix]
    environment: 
      name: ${{ matrix.CUSTOMENVNAME }}
    runs-on: 
      group: ARE-Shared
    
    strategy:
      matrix: 
        include: ${{fromJSON(needs.generate-matrix.outputs.DISMATRIX)}}
      fail-fast: false

    steps:

      - name: Split Matrix name for use 
        id: instancedetails
        run: |
          
          Write-Host "ENCODE@6.0 ${{ matrix.customenvName }}"          

I have used for loop to create this minimal test case however, my actual case gets entries from the database which can be one or more than one.
Output of JSON variable DISMATRIX when it works fine with $i -lt 3:
Run echo "[{"CUSTOMENVNAME":"CustomEnvName1","DISPLAYLIST":"StatCustomEnvName1"},{"CUSTOMENVNAME":"CustomEnvName2","DISPLAYLIST":"StatCustomEnvName2"}]"
[{
CUSTOMENVNAME:CustomEnvName1,DISPLAYLIST:StatCustomEnvName1},{CUSTOMENVNAME:CustomEnvName2,DISPLAYLIST:StatCustomEnvName2}]

Output of JSON variable DISMATRIX when it does not work with $i -lt 2:
Run echo "{"CUSTOMENVNAME":"CustomEnvName1","DISPLAYLIST":"StatCustomEnvName1"}"
{CUSTOMENVNAME:CustomEnvName1,DISPLAYLIST:StatCustomEnvName1}

I'm having difficulty with creating the desired JSON for both the conditions.
Thus, I need a generic solution to the creation of JSON strategy matrix that will help populate one or more jobs based on any dynamic condition. Can you please suggest?

Output generated JSON, please, and add to the question. Is it possible that the matrix values become literals instead of lists of literals?

@DeltaGeorge not sure how to print JSON in powershell. Tried $json = "${{ fromJSON(needs.generate-matrix.outputs.DISMATRIX) }}"           Write-Host $json but it simply prints -> Array

@DeltaGeorge Is it possible that the matrix values become literals instead of lists of literals? -> YES

Remove fromJSON: echo "${{ needs.generate-matrix.outputs.DISMATRIX }}"

Pleased do it in both cases and post the JSON

@DeltaGeorge i have updated original post with output of JSON for both cases.

Include expects a list.
Try this
DISMATRIX="$($dismatrix | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100)"
if ($i -eq 2) {
  echo "DISMATRIX=[$DISMATRIX]" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
}
else {
  echo "DISMATRIX=$DISMATRIX" >> "$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT"
}


solution first does not work while solution second does.
Second solution has syntax error -> This works $DISMATRIX="$($dismatrix | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 100)"
Please update your answer.

I was suspecting that solution 1 might not work.

Thank you for your expertise and understanding.
